# Cambiar source en NetBeans 8.2 , "lambda expresions are not supported in source 1.7"

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy intentando usar expresiones lambda pero al intentar copilarlas sale el siguiente error

> lambda expressions are no supported un -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que tengo instalado el jre8 y el jdk8, como haría para cambiarlo y poder usarlas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para usar [expresiones Lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) el requerimiento principal es usar como mínimo `JDK 8`, debes instalarlo y para configurarlo en tu proyecto, realiza lo siguiente:

Selecciona tu proyecto, botón derecho y selecciona "Properties":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En "Sources" -> "Source/Binary Format", **selecciona como mínimo el `JDK 8` o posterior para que puedas usar [expresiones Lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]